# Show equal items in the view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

My models:

```
class House < ActiveRecord::Base
    
    has_many :category_join_table
    has_many :categories, :through => :category_join_table

end
```

The categories are by example "lux", "ideal for two" etc.

```
class CategoryJoinTable < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :house
    belongs_to :category
end
```

My idea is to show on the house property show page other houses which a belong to the same category/categories. I can do this in the console:

```
a = Category.find(4)
a.houses
```

and get the correct houses which belong to the categories. But how can I do this in controller/model logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd personally create an instance method in the House model :

```
def related_houses
  House.joins(:categories).where("categories.id IN (?) AND houses.id != ?", self.categories, self.id)
end
```

You basically find all houses with at least one shared category, except the current house.

Then in the view, just loop over your house instance :

```
<% @house.related_houses.each do |related_house| %>
  <!-- OUTPUT related_house stuff HERE -->
<% end %>
```

And you should be done :) You can add a limit to related houses too if you want, and pass it as param from the view if need be (default 5 here):

```
def related_houses(limit = 5)
  House.joins(:categories).where("categories.id IN (?) AND houses.id != ?", self.categories, self.id).limit(limit)
end
```

Edited answer, didn't see your House had many categories first